# почему блок крутится не ровно?

Tags: html, css

```css
.delete_news{
 width: 28px;
 height: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: 0.4s linear;
 background-image: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Close_Icon_Dark-32.png);
 background-position: center center;
}
 
.delete_news:hover{
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='delete_news'><a href='delete_post'></a></div>
```

почему у меня на компьютере такой же код но у меня при наведении он крутится перестает на одну секунду и опять крутит

Comment: Не совсем понятна суть вопроса, такое ощущение что вы хотите крутить изображение без перерыва, в таком случае используйте animation.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp

Comment: @AntonEssential проблема в том что у меня на сранице крутит без перерыва, хоть и на сайте все нормально

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все потому, что Вы крутите блок, а не ссылку с изображением.
transition нужно применить к .delete_news a, transform к .delete_news a:hover и отцентрировать бэкграунд для ссылки background-position: 50% 50%;

```css
.delete_news{
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.delete_news a{
 background-image: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Close_Icon_Dark-32.png);
        background-position: 50% 50%;
 transition: 0.4s linear; 
 display: block;
 width: 24px;
 height: 28px;
}

.delete_news a:hover{
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class='delete_news'><a href='delete_post'></a></div>
```

Comment: все равно крутит